# Is there an easy way to Auto Fill a formula in Excel, where the Sheet reference is the only thing that changes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste, autofill, excel-indirect

I've left the default, Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. I have an formula that I want to run through all the sheets in a workbook:

- In `Sheet1,A1` I have: `=Sheet2!$A$3`.
- In `Sheet1,B1` I have: `=VLOOKUP("Total Data Used",Sheet2!$A$1:$G$555,4,FALSE)`

How do I copy that down to cover all 100 sheets, where the only change is the sheet number reference?

**For Example:**

Sheet1, A2 should be:
`=Sheet3!$A$3`

Sheet1, B2 should be:
`=VLOOKUP("Total Data Used",Sheet3!$A$1:$G$555,4,FALSE)`

Sheet1, A3 should be:
`=Sheet4!$A$3`

Sheet1, B3 should be:
`=VLOOKUP("Total Data Used",Sheet4!$A$1:$G$555,4,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try in Sheet1:

In A1:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()+1&"!$A$3")
```

and in B1 (both formulae copied down to suit):

```
=VLOOKUP("Total Data Used",INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()+1&"!"&"$A$1:$G$555"),4,FALSE)
```

With 100 sheets there may be a performance hit (INDIRECT is volatile).

Comment: That did it, thank you! Indirect is one of those I just don't think about!